# What is difference between maxLifetime and idleTimeout in HikariCP

Tags: hikaricp

When i set minimum `idleTimeout` then idle connections closed after 10 seconds.

```
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 150
      minimum-idle: 50
      idle-timeout: 10000
```

But even i set `maxLifeTime` 30 seconds then they closed either.

```
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 150
      minimum-idle: 50
      max-lifetime: 30000
```

Here's question.

What is difference between `maxLifeTime` and `idleTimeout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a connection is older than maxLifeTime when it is returned to the connection pool, it will be closed immediately.  If it sits idle for longer than idleTime, OR maxLifeTime, then it will close.